# multiplication in django template without using manually created template tag

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to achieve multiplication operation in `django template`. For example
I have the  values,
price=10.50
quantity=3

With the help of this link

http://slacy.com/blog/2010/07/using-djangos-widthratio-template-tag-for-multiplication-division/

I tried below codes for achieving it,

```
{% widthratio quantity 1 price %}
```

but it's returning only 31.  But I need the answer in float (31.5)

And I want to achieve it without using the manually created tags

How can I achieve it?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Compute the result in your view. There is a reason why they didn't implement such tags for the templates.

Comment: so your saying There is no way to do multiplication  in django template ?

Comment: You always use a [custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters).

Comment: any way thanks for the updates buddy..........

Comment: Added an answer. And I meant "You could **always** use a custom filter", sorry.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can use the built-in `widthratio` template tag.

- a*b use `{% widthratio a 1 b %}`
- a/b use `{% widthratio a b 1 %}`

Note: the results are rounded to an integer before returning.

@see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/

Comment: Is not possible to access to main number not the int?

Answer (score 32):

There are 2 approaches:

- Computing the values inside the view and pass them to the template (recommended in my opinion)
- Using template filters

In the manner of the [`add`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.2/django/template/defaultfilters.py#L658-L667) [filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#add), you could always create your own `multiply` filter, creating your own [custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters):

```py
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def multiply(value, arg):
    return value * arg
```

Then in your template, something like that should work.

```html
{{ quantity | multiply:price }}
```

This is not tested, and I never did this as - again - I find neater to compute datas inside the views and render **only** with the templates.

Comment: It means that i have to use custom filter..ok thanks buddy..i will go for it.

Comment: Don't forget to flag as answered if that answer helped you.

Answer (score 10):

Another approach that I have used seems cleaner to me. If you are going through a queryset, it doesn't make sense to compute the values in your view. Instead, add the calculation as a function in your model!

Let's say your model looks like this:

```
Class LineItem:
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2)
```

Simply add the following to the model:

```
    def line_total(self):
        return self.quantity * self.price
```

Now you can simply treat line_total as if it were a field in the record:

```
{{ line_item.line_total }}
```

This allows the `line_total` value to be used anywhere, either in templates or views, and ensures that it is always consistent, without taking up space in the database.

Comment: Agree in that's a more consistent solution, but I think the question was trying to get to some template-side solution for models on which you don't have access to.

Answer (score 5):

I know it's been so long since this question came out but, now there's a library called django-mathfilters which made mathematical operations easier in Django templates. you can easily write
`<li>42 * 0.5 = {{ answer|mul:0.5 }}</li>` for multiplication.

check it out  https://pypi.org/project/django-mathfilters/

Comment: this doesnt work, only works add function, but no "mul", it returns error. I'm using django 4.x

Comment: @oruchkin could u please show us the error message ?

Answer (score 1):

***Multiplication with variable in Django.***

```
1st: install & then register "mathfilters" at INSTALLED_APPS in setting.py 
2nd: Add {% load mathfilters %} in html Page 
3rd: Multiply with variable like{{response.notSatisfied|mul:100}}
```