# Multiply in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am looping through cart-items, and want to multiply quantity with unit-price like this:

```
{% for cart_item in cart.cartitem_set.all %}
{{cart_item.quantity}}*{{cart_item.unit_price}}
{% endfor %}
```

Is it possible to do something like that? any other way to do it !! Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [multiplication in django template without using manually created template tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350630/multiplication-in-django-template-without-using-manually-created-template-tag)

Comment: That's a clever use of a filter. I didn't think to use `cart_item.quantity` as the `value` and `cart_item.unit_price` as the `arg`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to use a custom template tag. Template filters only accept a single argument, while a custom template tag can accept as many parameters as you need, do your multiplication and return the value to the context.

You'll want to check out the Django [template tag documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/), but a quick example is:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag()
def multiply(qty, unit_price, *args, **kwargs):
    # you would need to do any localization of the result here
    return qty * unit_price
```

Which you can call like this:

```
{% load your_custom_template_tags %}

{% for cart_item in cart.cartitem_set.all %}
    {% multiply cart_item.quantity cart_item.unit_price %}
{% endfor %}
```

Are you sure you don't want to make this result a property of the cart item? It would seem like you'd need this information as part of your cart when you do your checkout.

Answer (score 41):

You can use `widthratio` builtin filter for multiplication and division.

**To compute A*B:** `{% widthratio A 1 B %}`

**To compute A/B:** `{% widthratio A B 1 %}`

source: [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#widthratio)

*Notice: For irrational numbers, the result will round to integer.*

Comment: Way faster than writing a custom tag for a simple operation

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for irrational values, ie, how do I multiply value by 1.5 (seems to truncate 1.5 to 1.0)

Comment: @NicholasHamilton correct, I didn't notice that. the results will round to an integer.

Answer (score 14):

Or you can set the property on the model:

```
class CartItem(models.Model):
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Supplier)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    @property
    def total_cost(self):
        return self.quantity * self.item.retail_price

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.item.product_name
```

Comment: Logic better at the model, this is the correct answer

Comment: how to access this in django template direclty?

Comment: Better solution, allows use of other filters

Comment: @ManojSahu (for present readers, I hope you found out long ago :-): Just use `{{ cart_item.total_cost }}`

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in template with filters.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters

From documentation:

Here’s an example filter definition:

```
def cut(value, arg):
    """Removes all values of arg from the given string"""
    return value.replace(arg, '')
```

And here’s an example of how that filter would be used:

```
{{ somevariable|cut:"0" }}
```