# How to use django forloop.counter0 in a math expression in template?

Tags: django, django-templates, built-in

I want to use [django built-in template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for) `forloop.counter0` in a math expression. This is what I came up with:

```
{% for category in categories %}
        <li class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="{{ forloop.counter0 * 0.1 }}s">
                //whatever
        </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Which I learn is wrong cause of this error:

> Could not parse the remainder: ' * 0.1' from 'forloop.counter0 * 0.1'

Is it anyway to solve this issue?

Isn't there anyway that I could use a built-in function in a math expression?

Comment: Yep you're right, I misunderstood the counter. You can't multiply in Django templates so you could use a custom template tag or use `widthratio` tag to do the trick https://stackoverflow.com/a/33280889/8196244

Answer (score 1):

One can use `widthratio` tag to achieve this, also you can use custom `templatetag`, as stated in the comment by Mauricio, but in `widthratio` the final value should be a *number* and cannot be a *float*, so that may be problem.

So there is a third way to achieve this by using [`template-filters`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters)

So for multiplication you can put this in your `templatetags`

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter(is_safe=False)
def multiply(value, arg):
    """Multiply the arg to the value."""
    try:
        return float(value) * float(arg)
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        try:
            return value * arg
        except Exception:
            return ''
```

and use this in template like

```
{{ forloop.counter0|multiply:'0.1' }}

{{ '0.002'|multiply:'0.21' }}  # Output : 0.00042
```

Here the `value` and the `arg` need not be `int`, it can be a `float` too, also no need of loading any tag for multiplication in templates.