# I want to multiply length in rowspan

Tags: django-templates

<th colspan="{{(unique_dates|length) * 2}}">{{ date|date:'M d, Y' }}</th>

> I want to multiply the dates length by 2 but it gives me an error

Is there a way to perform that code? or a way I can get the same results I want?

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588160/multiply-in-django-template#answer-19588661