# How do I code a count for double nested for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I'm trying to pass just the piece number to my html. This will be used to update the content of a selected tag with javascript. All of my tags are created by a double nested for loop in django. But from what I've tried I've had no success.

Here is the javascript code:

```
$('td#'+new_data['piece_number']).html(new_data['img']);
```

Here is the double nested for loop in question:

```
<table id="table" bgcolor="{{puzzle.color_hash}}">
    <tbody>
    {% for x in n_rows %}
        <tr id='r{{x}}'>
            {% for y in n_cols %}
                <td id='{{count}}' height='{{puzzle.piece_res_height}}' width='{{puzzle.piece_res_width}}'>
                </td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want the total iteration count in {{count}} but from my understanding django doesn't let you have variable manipulation in the renderer

I'm looking for a result such as a row by column table...

1   2   3

4   5   6

7   8   9

Where there are 3 rows and 3 columns. 9 pieces. each with a td id of the piece number

i.e. row 2 column 2 has a td id of 5

Comment: n_rows and n_cols are arrays send from view?

Comment: yeah. They are: 'n_rows':range(puzzle.number_rows), 
'n_cols':range(puzzle.number_columns)

Answer (score 1):

You can send two wariables instead one `count` to html file and change ida of id naming.

```
<td id='r{{x}}d{{y}}' height='{{puzzle.piece_res_height}}' width='{{puzzle.piece_res_width}}'>
```

**Edit - right solution**

Ok, I have two solutions for you.

Both use [custom template filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters).

File `app/templatetags/default_filters.py`

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

#first way
def mod(value, arg):
    return value % arg == 0

#second way
@register.filter(name='multiply')
def multiply(value, arg):
    return value*arg

register.filter('mod', mod)
```

Context send to template

```
class MainSiteView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "main_page.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MainSiteView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        n_rows = n_cols = 2
        context['max_nums'] = n_rows * n_cols
        context['n_rows'] = [0, 1]
        context['n_cols'] = [0, 1]
        context['number_of_columns'] = 2
        context['range'] = [x for x in range(n_cols * n_rows)]
        return context
```

And template

```
{% load default_filters %}
<table id="_table" bgcolor="{{puzzle.color_hash}}">
    <tbody>
    {% for x in range %}
        {% if not forloop.counter|mod:number_of_columns %}
        <tr id='_r{{x}}'>
        {% endif %}
                <td id='_{{forloop.counter0}}' height='{{puzzle.piece_res_height}}' width='{{puzzle.piece_res_width}}'>
                    ({{forloop.counter0}})
                </td>
        {% if forloop.counter|mod:number_of_columns %}
        </tr>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
<table id="table" bgcolor="{{puzzle.color_hash}}">
    <tbody>
    {% for x in n_rows %}
        <tr id='r{{x}}'>
            {% for y in n_cols %}
                <td id='{{x|multiply:number_of_columns|add:y}}' height='{{puzzle.piece_res_height}}' width='{{puzzle.piece_res_width}}'>
                    [{{x|multiply:number_of_columns|add:y}}]
                </td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you suggesting passing the data through the view to the html template?

Comment: I'm confused with your javascript. What's `new_data['piece_number']`?
It's number of field to change? Where it's come from? I'm afraid I was wrong about context_data...

Comment: It is passed from my django view.  return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'img':img, 'piece_number':piece_number})) it represents something like piece 1 or piece 2. it is concatenated like this 'td#'+new_data['piece_number']

Comment: Can you send data representing row and column of puzzle piece instead of `piece_number`? Then you could send `HttpResponse(json.dumps({'img':img, 'row':row, 'col':col}))` and use following javascript: `$('#r'+new_data['row']+'d'+new_data['col']).html(new_data['img']);`?

Comment: but this way I have to translate, django side, what piece goes where in the row column scheme. If I had a counter in my template than I could avoid the headache of determining the piece location.

Comment: so if it was piece 4 than I would have to ask what row is the piece in and what column the piece is in view.py side. Instead of just saying hey put piece 4 into the page.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I don't have Django IDE (now installing).
Wait a minute and read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350630/multiplication-in-django-template-without-using-manually-created-template-tag)