# Django template change 0.95 to 95

Tags: django, django-templates

It looks silly but I need to change a string value from 0.95 to 95 on django template language.

```
{{ Course.grade }}
```

Comment: String value rather than decimal/float? That's too complicated for the built in template tags to be the right way to do it. The easier approach is to give your model an accessor function that formats the value as you like it.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper you should make that an answer, not a comment.

Comment: You might like this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350630/multiplication-in-django-template-without-using-manually-created-template-tag

Comment: @joelgoldstick - the techniques at that question won't work on a string value. I'd have suggested `widthratio` as a hacky option for a numeric value (still preferring an accessor function on the model, or formatting the data in the view) but the question here says it's a string value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linked answer in the comments can be modified to work. An alternative would be to add a method to your `Course` model:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    ...
    grade = models.CharField(...)

    def get_grade_display(self):
        return int(100 * float(self.grade))
```

and use it in your templates:

```
{{ course.get_grade_display }}
```