# Use the same animation on different objects of same class

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600);

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'sans-serif';
  color: #cecece;
  background: #222;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item-1,
.item-2{
 position: absolute;
  display: block;
 top: 2em;

  width: 60%;

  font-size: 2em;

 animation-duration: 20s;
 animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.item-1{
 animation-name: anim-1;
}

.item-2{
 animation-name: anim-2;
}

@keyframes anim-1 {
 0%, 8.3% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
  8.3%,25% { left: 25%; opacity: 1; }
  33.33%, 100% { left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes anim-2 {
 0%, 8.3% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
  8.3%,25% { left: 25%; opacity: 1; }
  33.33%, 100% { left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
}

    </style>
</head>

{% for person in persons %}

<p class="item-1">
    Person Name: {{ persons.awards_type }}
    <br/>
    <br/>
    Person ID: {{ persons.awards_nomination }}
    <br/>
    Job: {{ persons.reason }}
</p>
{% endfor %}


</html>
```

I am new to CSS and HTML and wondering if I can use the same CSS animation on  different objects of same class. `persons` is a list of objects from class `Person` which contain the person's information.

I want to display each object in the `persons` list as an animation. Since the number of elements in the list may change I was wondering how can I achieve this.

I am using django to send the `persons` list to the HTML page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600);

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'sans-serif';
  color: #cecece;
  background: #222;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item-1{
    position: absolute;
  display: block;
    top: 2em;

  width: 60%;

  font-size: 2em;

    animation-duration: 20s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.item-1{
    animation-name: anim-1;
}


@keyframes anim-1 {
    0%, 8.3% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
  8.3%,25% { left: 25%; opacity: 1; }
  33.33%, 100% { left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
}


    </style>
</head>

{% for person in persons %}

<p class="item-1">
    Person Name: {{ person.person_name }}
    <br/>
    <br/>
    Person ID: {{ person.person_id }}
    <br/>
    Job: {{ person.occupation }}
</p>
{% endfor %}


</html>
```

The problem with the above code is all the names are getting overlapped on top of each other. Can somebody suggest whether we can achieve this result with CSS.
[image]

Comment: create a working snippet please - you have snippet button in edit toolbar here

Answer (score 0):

Try using css `animation-delay`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <style>
      @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600);
      body {
        font-family: 'Open Sans', 'sans-serif';
        color: #cecece;
        background: #222;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      .item-1,
      .item-2,
      .item-3,
      .item-4 {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        top: 2em;
        width: 60%;
        font-size: 2em;
        animation-duration: 20s;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        left: -100%;
        animation-name: anim-1;
      }

      .item-1 {
        animation-delay: 0s
      }

      .item-2 {
        animation-delay: 5s
      }

      .item-3 {
        animation-delay: 10s
      }

      .item-4 {
        animation-delay: 15s
      }

      @keyframes anim-1 {
        0%,
        8.3% {
          left: -100%;
          opacity: 0;
        }
        8.3%,
        25% {
          left: 25%;
          opacity: 1;
        }
        33.33%,
        100% {
          left: 110%;
          opacity: 0;
        }
      }

    </style>
  </head>



  <p class="item-1">
    Person Name: 1
    <br/>
    <br/> Person Identification: 1
    <br/> Job: 1
  </p>
  <p class="item-2">
    Person Name: 2
    <br/>
    <br/> Person Identification: 2
    <br/> Job: 2
  </p>
  <p class="item-3">
    Person Name: 3
    <br/>
    <br/> Person Identification: 3
    <br/> Job: 3
  </p>
  <p class="item-4">
    Person Name: 4
    <br/>
    <br/> Person Identification: 4
    <br/> Job:4
  </p>



</html>
```

Comment: I don't know how many items are there in the list. I have to make it dynamic instead of static. Can you please edit your answer. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: just add inline css based on the for loops index
        `<p class="item-1" style="animation-delay:{{index}}s">`

Comment: <p class="item-1" style="animation-delay:{{ forloop.counter0 }}s">, instead of index I have used forloop.counter0. But the problem I am facing is that the second object's animation is coming like after a second and getting overlapped over the first object info.

Comment: can you multiply the counter index `{{ forloop.counter0 * 5 }}s`

Comment: Throws an error. Could not parse the remainder: ' * 5' from 'forloop.counter0 * 5' . Appreciate your response

Comment: But your solution seems brilliant, should find a way for multiplying the time delay.

Comment: are you using Django templating? would this help in multiplying https://stackoverflow.com/a/24180121/8285970

Comment: `{{ widthratio forloop.counter0 1 5 }}s`

Comment: {% widthratio forloop.counter 1 10 %}s This solved the problem. But I am having another issue. https://imgur.com/JbAWPnH

Comment: did you add `left: -100%;` to `.item-1` css

Comment: This solved the issue. But there is some inconsistency with the timing. I did set my animation-duration to 40s and {% widthratio forloop.counter 1 10 %}s. This adds a delay of 10 sec before start, and the animation just stays for few seconds like 5 seconds, starts the animation for second object, stays for another 5 seconds and the whole screen goes blank for 20 sec. I dont understand why animation is staying only for 5 seconds

Comment: i'd think it would have something to do with your `@keyframes` percentages

Comment: This doesn't make the page dynamic, the reason is the animation delay for anim-1 is 30 seconds and lets say the for loop is repeated 5 times with a delay of 10 seconds, the first and the fourth objects overlap on each other because the fourth object in the list starts at 30 seconds and the first object starts again since repeat is infinite.