# how to get all data of price, qty from html in js and multiple it accordingly and add it into html in Django. anyone help me

Tags: javascript, arrays, django, django-templates

I have attached the HTML on Photo
Question - how to get all data of price, qty from HTML in js and multiple it accordingly and add it into HTML in Django. anyone help me.

```
const x = document.getElementById("qty").innerHTML;
const y = document.getElementById("price").innerHTML;
const z = document.getElementById("total");

function calculator(qty, price) {
  let lowercase = price.toLowerCase();
  const remove_price_string = lowercase.replace("only", "");
  console.log(remove_price_string);
  let total = remove_price_string * qty;
  console.log(total);
}

calculator(x, y);
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: Models.py]

Comment: Downvoting because code is included as screenshots rather than text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that each bill is a Django model object. The easiest way to do this calculation in Django is to [add it as a function to your model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350630/multiplication-in-django-template-without-using-manually-created-template-tag):

```python
# models.py
from django.db import models
import re

class Bill(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    food_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    qty = models.IntegerField()

    # Ideally, you would represent the price using
    # a DecimalField. 
    # price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2)
    # only = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    # However, you said you're using a string instead.
    price = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    # If price was a DecimalField, you could do a simple
    # calculation.
    #def total(self):
    #    return self.qty * self.price

    # However, since it's a string, you'll have to
    # convert it to a whole number first.
    def total(self):
        """Computes the total bill from the quantity and price."""
        # Remove non-numeric strings like 'only'
        # from the price. Warning: this will remove
        # decimal points too, so it only works with
        # whole numbers as prices.
        price = re.sub("[^0-9]", "", self.price)

        # Convert it to a whole number so we can do
        # math on it.
        price = int(price)

        # Return the calculated result
        return self.qty * price
```

You can call this function in your template by typing its name, without parentheses:

```html
<td id="total">{{ bill.total }}</td>
```

Please be careful about how you represent currencies. If you need to represent fractional amounts, use a `DecimalField` with an appropriate number of decimal places set; otherwise, use an `IntegerField`. You should never use a `FloatField` to represent currencies, as it does not always store an exact representation of a currency amount.

Comment: hmm, @jeff, I have already made a model and mentioned the price as String because after adding the price user might like to add "only" that's  why could suggest me how we can do it from javascript or from models also how can we remove string values on models

Comment: @ShivaGiri When you store the price that way, you make it difficult to apply computations to the price. If you think about it, your String really contains two pieces of information: the price, and an optional "only". The price can be represented with a `DecimalField` as shown above. The presence of "only" can be represented with a `BooleanField` that has a default value of False.

This change is easy to make if you don't already have database data that's based on the old model. Do you already have `Bill` objects in your database that you can't just delete?

Comment: @ShivaGiri I changed the `price` attribute of the `Bill` model to a String above, to better match your existing model. However, I left my recommended model attributes in comments, in case you want to make your model easier to work with.