# How to multiply two variables together in HTML template DJANGO

Tags: html, django

I have this page that lists various info on a specific stock including orders that have been placed on that specific item. I would like to display how much money the user of this system would get from that specific order.

```
<table class='table'>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ORDER ID</th>
            <th>NAME</th>
            <th>AMOUNT ORDERED</th>
            <th>REVENUE</th>
            <th>ORDERED ITEM</th>
            <th>ADDRESS</th>
            <th>CITY</th>
            
          </tr>
        </thead>
      {% for x in queryset2 %}
          <tr>
            <td>{{x.id}}</td>
            <td>{{x.name}}</td>
            <td>{{x.quantity}}</td>
            <td>{{x.quantity * stock.ppu}}</td>
            <td>{{x.order_item}}</td>
            <td>{{x.address}}</td>
            <td>{{x.city}}</td>
          </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

I have this code so far. What would be the correct syntax to multiply these two variables together : {{x.quantity * stock.ppu}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not write arithmetic expressions in a Django template. You should write this in the view, for example by annotating the queryset:

```
from django.db.models import F

# …

queryset2 = queryset2.annotate(
    total_value=F('quantity') * F('ppu')
)
```

then in the template you render this as:

```
<td>{{ x.total_value }}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do math operations in the Django template you can use this [django-mathfilters](https://pypi.org/project/django-mathfilters/)

but if you try to use a built-in way to do, can follow [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#add) to add and Subtraction

Example:

```
{{x.quantity | add: stock.ppu}}
```

to do multiplication and division you can use [widthratio](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#widthratio)

Example:

```
a*b use {% widthratio a 1 b %}
a/b use {% widthratio a b 1 %}
```

from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24180121/8464131)

or you can make your own [custom tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/)

for add

```
@register.filter
def add_value(value, arg):
    return value + arg
```

for subtract

```
@register.filter
def subtract(value, arg):
    return value - arg
```

then use them in your template like this

```
{{x.quantity | subtract: stock.ppu}}
```